# Application Installation Failed - Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, failed-installation

I am a newbie to Android. I am trying to install the application from Android Studio into my real device (Redmi 4). I never installed this before but I get this message.

[image]

When I press OK I get following error:

```
Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565))
Error while Installing APKs
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Usually Redmi devices ask for installation on device with a 10 second auto deny alert . So i suggest you to reconnect it and allow it to run the application .

Comment: @ADM I have already tried many times

Comment: Is `MIUI Optimization` is turned off in your device ?

Comment: Yes it's already off @Heisen-Berg

Comment: Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49080901/application-installation-failed-android-studio-3-0-1?noredirect=1#comment85167486_49080901 for more info.

Comment: @Heisen-Berg Its this question's link

Comment: I already got a solution. I never installed an app which has mentioned in my question @DakshAgrawal

Comment: @user6788419 how did you resolve it ? Can you please share ?

Comment: @Vivek see the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved the issue.

Go to Device **Settings** -> **Developer Options** -> Turn ON **Install via USB**